# How to change base path of Solr example?

Tags: configuration, jetty, solr

I've followed the [Solr tutorial](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/tutorial.html), but the URL they make you use is:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/
```

What is the most simple way to change this URL to:

```
http://localhost:8983/foobar/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured it out myself. What I did was, inside the example directory, rename

```
webapps/solr.war
```

to

```
webapps/foobar.war
```

Also, I changed a line in solr/conf/scripts.conf to

```
webapp_name=foobar
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Solr with Jetty, you can change it in `webdefault.xml`.
Detailed instructions [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrJetty)

Answer (score 1):

Seems a little different in 2014 with Solr 4.10:

From the "example" directory or your equivalent:

1. edit contexts/solr-jetty-context.xml 
   `<Set name="contextPath"><SystemProperty name="hostContext" default="/foobar"/></Set>`
2. edit solr/collectionName/conf/scripts.conf : change webapp_name=foobar
3. java -jar start.jar

I'm not sure where the webapp_name parameter is used but it seems reasonable to keep this.